# Returning a Value from excel using Pandas fails without error message. Returns this instead: <function read_value_from_excel at 0x000001B8C569AD30>

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently trying to build my own excel reader and tried to imitate/reproduce the results from this simple excersice :
https://techoverflow.net/2021/08/01/how-to-read-single-value-from-xlsx-using-pandas/

My program is supposed to return a string from the the excelfile `"Test.xlsx"`, `column "C"`, `row 3`.
It's supposed to return `Test Value #123`
The Excel file is completely empty, it only contains this one cell with something in it.

Here is what I get instead when I print the value:

```
<function read_value_from_excel at 0x000001B8C569AF70>
```

What do I have to do to return the wanted value?

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "Test.xlsx"


def read_value_from_excel(filename, column="C", row=3):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None, names=["Value"]).iloc[0]["Value"]

print(read_value_from_excel)
```

Comment: can you print the value inside the defination... and if you want to call a defination, you need to pass the parameters as well like `print( read_value_from_excel(filename))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send specified parameters when calling the function. Use:

```
print(read_value_from_excel(real_filename, your_column, your_row))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What do you mean by the real filename? The file is in the same folder as my python program.

Comment: The path to your excel file.

Comment: Thank you! ok.... I will do that, but I am really confused because I just worked on another program and no filepath was needed....

Comment: You're welcome, please note that the problem was not with setting complete path file. If your files are within the same directory you do not need to specify that, just excel file name needed.